# Installing a fiberglass shower in basement

Tags: basement, shower, drain, rough-in

I have an acrylic preformed shower to install in my basement. There is a rough in drain in a 10x10 cutout. I have two questions.

1. The shower hole for the drain is in the center of the shower so it will be about 10 inches from the rough in pipe.

   - The shower has a skirt that is almost 4 inches high.
   - I found a shower drain that has a side outlet that will fit between the concrete floor and the shower pan.
   - Basically it would cause the drain to have a quick 90 degree turn and then I can add another 90 down the stub a few inches away. (All 2 inch PVC).
   - Does that seem reasonable as opposed to tearing up concrete?
   - I worry because I only found a couple brands of side outlet drains. It seems that there would be a lot more out there if this was an acceptable solution to an offset drain.
2. The shower needs concrete underneath.

   - Do I also fill in the 10x10 cut-out with concrete?
   - It seems obvious that I would, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there's that much clearance under the shower?  I realize you have a 4" skirt but the floor usually drops back down to finished floor level.

I would be concerned with those two 90's so close together. you'd never get a snake down there if you had a clog. If you're going through all this work for a shower, take the time to do the drain right and bust up a little concrete. You would fill in the cutout with concrete. The floor of the shower will flex if not supported correctly. Supporting the floor will be easier with a straight down drain.

Comment: Thanks. It is somewhere between 3-1/2 to 4 inches off the ground at the drain. The schematic says 3-1/2, but it is a little higher. 
The drain has a built in 90, the down pipe is exactly 11.5 inches from the shower hole so a 90 sweep fits just fine. Anyway you confirmed what my gut told me...break up the concrete and fill the cut out.

Comment: You can use a diamond wheel on an angle grinder to cut around the section to be removed.  Keeps it neat and minimal, and cracks don't shoot out in weird directions through the remaining slab.  You may even chose to cut more slices in the part to be removed to make it easier to chunk out.

Comment: Putting in a trap I hope